# Как правильно в NodeJS вызвать модуль внутри другого модуля и использовать потом его?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Есть вот такой основной файл:

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function main() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/');
    console.log(response);
    var provider = require('./providers/prov');
    provider.parse();
}

main()
    .then(() => {
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

И файл модуля ./providers/prov.js

```
const axios = require("axios");

this.parse = async function() {
  console.log(1);
  const HTML = await axios.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/');
  console.log(HTML);
}
```

Проблема в том, что внутри модуля первый вывод в консоль срабатывает, выводит единичку, а второй исходный код не выводит. В основном файле то же самое срабатывает нормально.

Скажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно добавить await перед вызовом provider.parse();